# Easiest way to disable @hide annotations when compiling Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm developing a system app that uses hidden methods. I've added framework.jar to the compile-time classpath, so the app compiles and works fine, however, IDE doesn't know about these methods, so I have no autocompletion and there're lots of «red lines» in the editor.

I want to re-compile the SDK with `@hide` annotation disabled. There should be several ways to do that, for example, just to remove `@hide` from every place in the source code, but it's too invasive way, as it touches lots of source files.

I think that it can be somehow disabled by removing few (or even a single) arguments from command-line args to `metalava` in the AOSP build files, but I can't find where exactly it's called to strip hidden methods.

So, what is the easiest and less invasive way to do this?

Comment: Try to replace android.jar in sdk dir with your added framework.jar

Comment: @Yong thanks, it worked for non-hidden things like new constants, but it still doesn't see members annotated with `@hide`

Comment: Is your app going to be built independently using gradle or will it be built with the rest of AOSP using soong/make? If it is built with AOSP then I recommend using IntelliJ instead of Android Studio and then adding all the relevant Java source paths in frameworks/base to the IDE configuration.